# NameError: global name 'q' is not defined

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was able run the Hello World program in the google app engine in below link 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/

But after I have modified the code for the main.py file (Trying out new handler) I am getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/natesan/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/natesan/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/natesan/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/natesan/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/home/natesan/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/home/natesan/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/natesan/webapps/udacity1/main.py", line 29, in get
    self.request.get(q)
NameError: global name 'q' is not defined
```

The main.py file is as below.

```
import webapp2

form="""
<form action="/Testform">
    <input name="q" >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
"""
class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.request.get(q)
        self.response.write(q)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(form) 

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),('/Testform',TestHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Can anyone please help me out what the error is.

Comment: The error is exactly what Python is telling you it is. Where have you defined `q`? On what line have you given it a value? :) It's not going to magically know what `q` refers to. If you want "q" to be treated as a string, put it in double quotes like `"q"`.

Comment: write `"q"` not `q`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **write** `q` **in quotes** like this: `"q"`.

Without quotes, `q` will be treated as a *variable* and since you haven't *declared* it, the error is raised.

I modified the TestHandler class as below.

```
class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        q=self.request.get("q")
        self.response.write(q)
```

Assign a value to the variable `q=self.request.get("q")` and display it in the browser with `self.response.write(q)`

Comment: My intention was to display the content I type in the form ,get that in variable called "q" . I have modified the code lines as `q=self.request.get("q")` so that `self.response.write(q)` works the way I want it to . Thank you for the pointing it out.